# failed to lazily initialize on 2nd call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a lazy init issue. 
When a call a methode once inside my service it works.
But when it called Twice, it fails on the second call.

Pb is on **component traitementFinancier**.**partieReglement** or **partieEncaissement**
When I try to loop on one of these I have a lazy init issue

From a struts action (old application) I call a service calling iteself a service and several daos.

I believe I have a problem with the session.

Mapping is :

```
<class name="com....UniteTraitement" table="UT" discriminator-value="0" abstract="true">
        <id name="pk" type="integer" column="PK_UT" unsaved-value="null">
            <generator class="com....PkGenerator">
                <param name="table">SEQUENCE</param>
                <param name="primary_key_column">ENTITE</param>
                <param name="primary_key_value">UT</param>
                <param name="value_column">NUMERO</param>
            </generator>
        </id>

        <discriminator column="CLASSE" type="integer" />
        <timestamp column="DATE_VERSION" name="version" unsaved-value="null" />

        <property name="dateCreation" type="timestamp" column="DATE_CREATION" />
        <property name="estDossierPhysique" column="DOSSIER_PHYSIQUE" />
        <property name="estDossierCSI" column="DOSSIER_CSI" />
        <property name="identifiant" column="IDENTIFIANT_UT" />
        <property name="identifiantVarianteGarantie" column="IDENTIFIANT_VARIANTE_GARANTIE" />
        <property name="numero" column="NUMERO_UT" />
        <property name="risqueEstGaranti" column="RISQUE_EST_GARANTI" />
        <property name="statut" column="STATUT" />
        <property name="motifAbandon" column="MOTIF_ABANDON" />
        <property name="cogestionInspecteur" column="COGESTION_INSPECTEUR" />
.....
        <list name="histoFiltreControleGarantie" 
              cascade="all, delete-orphan" 
              fetch="select">           
            <key column="PK_UT" not-null="true" />
            <list-index column="NUMERO_VERSION" base="1"/> 
            <one-to-many class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.uniteTraitement.HistoFiltreControleGarantie" />
        </list>

        <bag name="etapesFiltreControleGarantie" 
              cascade="all, delete-orphan" 
              fetch="select"
              order-by="NUMERO_VERSION desc, POSITION">
            <key column="PK_UT" not-null="true" />          
            <one-to-many class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.uniteTraitement.EtapeFiltreControleGarantie" />
        </bag> 

        <component name="traitementFinancier"
            class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.TraitementFinancier" lazy="true">

            <property name="dateRevisionEvaluations" type="timestamp" column="DATE_REVISION_EVALUATIONS" />

            <many-to-one name="partieReglement" column="PK_PARTIE_REGLEMENT"
                class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.PartieFinanciere" unique="true" cascade="all"
                fetch="select" />

            <many-to-one name="partieEncaissement" column="PK_PARTIE_ENCAISSEMENT"
                class="com.prima.solutions.primaclaims.core.modele.sinistre.financier.PartieFinanciere" unique="true" cascade="all"
                fetch="select" />

            ....
        </component>
</class>
```

Service calls are

```
    Struts action
          ....
           FinancierService financierService = AnnotationContextCoreLocator.getInstance().getBean(FinancierService.class);
            try {
                financierService.modifierEvaluations(ctxService, pkUt, evalReglement, evalEncaissement,
                        new Boolean(evaluationBO.getEstDossierCSI()), TraitementFinancier.ORIGINE_OPERATEUR);
            } catch (ExceptionValidation e) {
                sauverMessages(session, e.getConteneur());
            }
      .....
end struts action
```

Financier Service method

```
public void modifierEvaluations(ContexteService contexte, Integer pkUT, Evaluation evalReglements, Evaluation evalEncaissements,
            Boolean estDossierCSI, int origine) throws ExceptionValidation 
    {
        UniteTraitement ut = utDao.rechercherUTComplete(pkUT);
        QualificationUT qualif = ut.getQualification();
        Gestionnaire gestionnaire = gestionnaireDao.rechercherGestionnaire(contexte.getIdentifiantUtilisateur());
        verificationHabilitationService.verifierDroitTraitement(gestionnaire, ut);
        // L'UniteTraitement peut être fermée, dans ce cas il s'agit d'une réouverture...


        // VALIDATION (1ère partie)
        ...


        // Analyse du résultat, pour impact au niveau des statuts (MEF) et au niveau du risque (donc compta)
        Object[] resultat = financierDao.modifierEvaluations(gestionnaire, pkUT, modeR, suspensR, modeE, suspensE, ventilationBO);
        ut = (UniteTraitement) resultat[0];
        TraitementFinancier traitementFinancier = ut.getTraitementFinancier();
        HistoriquePartie actePartieRegl = (HistoriquePartie) resultat[1];
        HistoriquePartie actePartieEnc = (HistoriquePartie) resultat[2];

        // Partie règlement
        PartieFinanciere partieReglement = traitementFinancier.getPartieReglement();
        Boolean premiereOuvertureRegl = traiterPartieFinanciere(
            partieReglement, actePartieRegl, contexte, ut, gestionnaire, origine, evalReglements, true);
        // Partie encaissement
        PartieFinanciere partieEncaissement = traitementFinancier.getPartieEncaissement();
        Boolean premiereOuvertureEnc = traiterPartieFinanciere(
            partieEncaissement, actePartieEnc, contexte, ut, gestionnaire, origine, evalEncaissements, false); 

        // VALIDATION POST MAJ
        if (!contexte.isForcerService()) {
            ...
        }

        ....
    }
```

On 1st call for PartieFinanciere partieReglement it works
On 2nd call for PartieFinanciere partieEncaissement it works

```
private Boolean traiterPartieFinanciere(PartieFinanciere partieFinanciere, HistoriquePartie historiquePartie, 
                                            ContexteService contexte, UniteTraitement ut, Gestionnaire gestionnaire,
                                            int origine, Evaluation evaluation, Boolean isReglement) 
    {
        boolean premiereOuverture = false;

        QualificationUT qualif = ut.getQualification();
        Declaration declaration = qualif.getDeclaration();
        Sinistre sinistre = qualif.getSinistre();

        if (historiquePartie != null) {
            ContexteStatutPartieFinanciere ctx = mefManagerService.getContexteStatutPartieFinanciere(gestionnaire, partieFinanciere.getPk(), ut.getPk(), sinistre
                    .getPk(), declaration.getPk(), partieFinanciere.getStatut());
            ctx.getStatutCourant().traiterEvaluation(ctx);

            String acteGestion;
            String typeActe = historiquePartie.getActe();
            Date dateActe = historiquePartie.getDate();
            if (typeActe.equals(HistoriquePartie.ACTE_OUVERTURE)) {
                ...
            } else if (typeActe.equals(HistoriquePartie.ACTE_MODIFICATION_EVALUATION)) {
                ...
            } else if (typeActe.equals(HistoriquePartie.ACTE_REOUVERTURE)) {
                syntheseRisqueDao.traiterReouverture(ut, partieFinanciere, dateActe, isReglement, origine);
                acteGestion = ActeGestion.NATURE_REOUVERTURE_PARTIE;
            } else
                acteGestion = null;

            // ACTE DE GESTION
            if (acteGestion != null) {
                String identifiantVG = ut.getIdentifiantVarianteGarantie();
                if (identifiantVG == null)
                    throw new ExceptionProprieteRequise("identifiantVarianteGarantie", UniteTraitement.class, ut.getPk());
                VarianteGarantie vg = produitService.rechercherVarianteGarantie(identifiantVG);
                Risque risque = vg.getRisque();
                gestionnaireDao.creerActeGestion(acteGestion, new Object[] { risque.getCode(), risque.getLibelle(), evaluation.getSuspens(),
                        "Règlement", Evaluation.LIBELLES_MODES.get(evaluation.getMode()) }, contexte.getIdentifiantUtilisateur(), declaration
                        .getPk(), ut.getPk(), declaration.getIdentifiant(), ut.getIdentifiant());
            }
        }

        return premiereOuverture;
    }
```

IT FAILS IN **syntheseRisqueDao.traiterReouverture(...)**
when rechercherInfosRisqueEtMettreAJourStatut is called for the 2nd time

```
public void traiterReouverture(UniteTraitement ut, PartieFinanciere partieFinanciere, Date dateActe, boolean reglement, int origine) {
        // Très similaire à ouverture... une différence cependant, trouvez là ;) !
        Session session = sf.getCurrentSession();

        // Recherche des informations utiles sur la synthese risque
        InformationsRisque infos = rechercherInfosRisqueEtMettreAJourStatut(session, ut, partieFinanciere.getPk(), reglement, dateActe);

        ....
    }
```

Last method : CRASH when trying to loop on 
HistoriqueOperation historiqueOperation : historique

```
private InformationsRisque rechercherInfosRisqueEtMettreAJourStatut(Session session, UniteTraitement ut, Integer pkPartieFinanciere, boolean reglement, Date dateActe) {
        Sinistre sinistre = ut.getQualification().getSinistre();
        String identifiantVG = ut.getIdentifiantVarianteGarantie();

        SyntheseRisque synthese = null;
        if( !sinistre.getSynthesesRisque().isEmpty() ) {
            synthese = sinistre.getSynthesesRisque().iterator().next();
        }

        if (synthese == null) {
            synthese = new SyntheseRisque();
            synthese.setIdentifiantVarianteGarantie(identifiantVG);
            sinistre.getSynthesesRisque().add(synthese);
            session.save(synthese);
        }

        InformationsRisque infos = new InformationsRisque();
        infos.sinistre = sinistre;
        infos.synthese = synthese;

        List<PartieFinanciere> listeParties = rechercherPartiesFinancieresRisque(session, infos, reglement);
        infos.nouveauStatut = calculerStatutSyntheseRisque(listeParties);

        Set<HistoriqueOperation> historique = synthese.getHistoriqueEncaissements();
        if(reglement) {
            historique = synthese.getHistoriqueReglements();
        }
        infos.historique=historique;
        infos.opsJour=new ArrayList<HistoriqueOperation>();
        infos.opsPrecedentes=new ArrayList<HistoriqueOperation>();

        // Debut du jour
        Calendar calendrier = Calendar.getInstance();
        ....
        Date dateDebutJour = calendrier.getTime();
        // Fin du jour
        ...
        Date dateFinJour = calendrier.getTime();

        // CRASH HERE when the method is called for the second time
        for (HistoriqueOperation historiqueOperation : historique) {
            // operations jour
            if( historiqueOperation.getDate().after(dateDebutJour) && historiqueOperation.getDate().before(dateFinJour) ) {
                infos.opsJour.add(historiqueOperation);
            }
            // operations precedents
            if( historiqueOperation.getDate().before(dateDebutJour) ) {
                infos.opsPrecedentes.add(historiqueOperation);
            }
        }

        // Mise à jour du statut, après avoir conservé l'ancien
        infos.ancienStatut = reglement ? synthese.getStatutEvaluationsReglements() : synthese.getStatutEvaluationsEncaissements();

        // Comme on n'est pas capable de calculer directement réouvert à partir des statuts d'UT,
        // on met réouvert lorsque le statut précédent n'était pas ouvert...
        if (SyntheseRisque.STATUT_OUVERT.equals(infos.nouveauStatut) && infos.ancienStatut != null && !SyntheseRisque.STATUT_OUVERT.equals(infos.ancienStatut)) {
            infos.nouveauStatut = SyntheseRisque.STATUT_REOUVERT;
        }
        if (reglement) {
            synthese.setStatutEvaluationsReglements(infos.nouveauStatut);
        } else {
            synthese.setStatutEvaluationsEncaissements(infos.nouveauStatut);
        }

        return infos;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution It's the evict set in the code of one method. 
On the 2nd call, because off session.evict(...) object is set out the session.
It was not easy to find it because of multiple embedded calls.
This code is a legacy of a pretty old (2006) and bad coded application.